# How to remove first </p> and last <p> tag in a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$str = '<div class="content"><br /> 
<strong>0730</strong> – Check in direct to Compass at Marlin Wharf Berth 18</p> <p><strong>0800 </strong> – Depart Marlin Marina Cairns to the Great Barrier Reef</p> 
<p><strong>1015</strong> – Arrive at your first Great Barrier Reef Location</p> <p><strong>1230</strong> – BBQ Lunch with fresh salads</p> 
<p><strong>1300</strong> Cruise to 2nd Reef Location 1530 – Depart the Great Barrier Reef</p> 
<p><strong>1730</strong> – Approximately Arrival time at Cairns Marina<br /> </div>';
```

I want to use `preg_replace` function to remove first `</p>` and last `<p>` tag because they are redundant, I have used this pattern but it didn't work.

```
$patterns = array(
            '#^\s*</p>#',
            '#<p>\s*$#',
);

$str = preg_replace( $patterns, '', $str );
```

Comment: did it just do nothing at all? or what happened?

Comment: can you not format the html properly to begin with or is this from an external site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088889/c-sharp-regex-replace-the-first-and-last-occurrence-of-double-quote-in-each-line would I think be what you want to do/have in essence

Comment: @Thomas: yes, it didn't change anything in my string, is my pattern wrong?

Comment: @RamRaider: it's in my site, i have a lot of strings like this, because of user's mistakes and I want to auto replace all strings, not manual remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with one expression:

```
$str = preg_replace("#(.*?)</p>(.*)<p>(.*)#s", "$1$2$3", $str, 1 );
```

This will do a non-greedy capture of text before the first `</p>`, then capture text greedily until `<p>` (which will be the last one because of the greediness). And finally the remaining text is also captured. The three captured groups are maintained, the 2 tags are not.

The `s` modifier is needed to allow the dot to also match new line characters.

Note that this does not check whether the removal is actually needed. It just does it, so if the `HTML` was already OK, you will get an non-desirable result.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you need

```
$str = '<div class="content"><br />
<strong>0730</strong> – Check in direct to Compass at Marlin Wharf Berth 18</p> <p><strong>0800 </strong> – Depart Marlin Marina Cairns to the Great Barrier Reef</p>
<p><strong>1015</strong> – Arrive at your first Great Barrier Reef Location</p> <p><strong>1230</strong> – BBQ Lunch with fresh salads</p>
<p><strong>1300</strong> Cruise to 2nd Reef Location 1530 – Depart the Great Barrier Reef</p>
<p><strong>1730</strong> – Approximately Arrival time at Cairns Marina<br /> </div>';

//Replace the first one, easy enough
$str = preg_replace('/<\/p>/', "", $str, 1);

$stringReplace = "<p>";
$stringLen = strlen($stringReplace);

//Get the position of the last one, with strrpos (reverse check)
$pos = strrpos($str, $stringReplace);

//Make sure there is one
if($pos !== false){
    //If so, replace it with nothing
    $str = substr_replace($str, "", $pos, $stringLen);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use something like this. but i don't check it myself. so let me and others know if it works or not.

```
$text = "Quick \"brown fox jumps \"over\" the lazy\" dog";
$resault = Regex.Replace(text, "(?<=^[^\"]*)\"|\"(?=[^\"]*$)", "\"\"\"");
```

Comment: This answer doesn't tailor to his question whatsoever, nor is it a correct PHP function, I think it's actually C# ?

Comment: this definitely not from php